# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 with TinyMCE Editor Image Upload

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

So I am working on a blog CMS and I am trying give my TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor the ability to upload images when a user is creating a post. I'm using the actual code from the TinyMCE Docs (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/), but when I attempt to upload an image, it gets stuck loading and gives an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload". Any ideas on what may be causing this? I've seen a few questions about this online, but they all seem to involve jQuery which I am not using. And sorry if this is too much of a question. Thanks for your time.

JavaScript (Top of body)

```
<script>
    function example_image_upload_handler (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) {
        var xhr, formData;

        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php');

        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            progress(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
        };

        xhr.onload = function() {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status === 403) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status, { remove: true });
                return;
            }

            if (xhr.status < 200 || xhr.status >= 300) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }

            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }

            success(json.location);
        };

        xhr.onerror = function () {
            failure('Image upload failed due to a XHR Transport error. Code: ' + xhr.status);
        };

        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

        xhr.send(formData);
    };

    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tinymce',
        height: 450,
        plugins: [
        'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
        'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
        'table emoticons template paste help'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ' +
        'bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | ' +
        'forecolor backcolor emoticons | help',
        menu: {
        favs: {title: 'My Favorites', items: 'code visualaid | searchreplace | emoticons'}
        },
        menubar: 'favs file edit view insert format tools table help',
        content_css: 'css/content.css',
        images_upload_handler: example_image_upload_handler
    });
</script>
```

PHP (upload.php)

```
<?php
  $accepted_origins = array("http://localhost");
  $imageFolder = "post-img/";

  reset ($_FILES);
  $temp = current($_FILES);
  if (is_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'])){
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
      // same-origin requests won't set an origin. If the origin is set, it must be valid.
      if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $accepted_origins)) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
      } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 403 Origin Denied");
        return;
      }
    }

    /*
      If your script needs to receive cookies, set images_upload_credentials : true in
      the configuration and enable the following two headers.
    */
    // header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    // header('P3P: CP="There is no P3P policy."');

    // Sanitize input
    if (preg_match("/([^\w\s\d\-_~,;:\[\]\(\).])|([\.]{2,})/", $temp['name'])) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid file name.");
        return;
    }

    // Verify extension
    if (!in_array(strtolower(pathinfo($temp['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)), array("gif", "jpg", "png"))) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid extension.");
        return;
    }

    // Accept upload if there was no origin, or if it is an accepted origin
    $filetowrite = $imageFolder . $temp['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($temp['tmp_name'], $filetowrite);

    // Respond to the successful upload with JSON.
    // Use a location key to specify the path to the saved image resource.
    // { location : '/your/uploaded/image/file'}
    echo json_encode(array('location' => $filetowrite));
  } else {
    // Notify editor that the upload failed
    header("HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error");
  }
?>
```

Comment: press f12, go to the network tab, look at what loaded from the server... unexpected token < when you are expecting json is the first <html> tag that gets sent as a response when php sends an error message instead of the json... check the response in the dev tools with f12 and you should be able to see what went wrong.

Comment: So I looked around in the network tab and the only 404 I get is "content.css" from the TinyMCE CDN. The console tab says the error is at ```json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);``` and from what I can tell, this is the response being returned: "{"location":"post-img\/sunset.jpg"}". The TinyMCE Docs say the response should look something like this: "{ location : '/uploaded/image/path/image.png' }".

Comment: Also getting this error "failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\site\blog-admin\upload.php</b> on line <b>48</b>"

Comment: I made sure all the paths were correct and am getting this response now: "{"location":"http:\/\/localhost\/blog-kellumws\/post-img\/consite.jpg"}" it seems weird to me that it adds both back and forward slashes. Could this be the problem?

Comment: the response you are getting back is basic json?... you aren't looking for a 404, you are looking at the response being sent that is in question. the response preview is valid json - not a php error?

Comment: position zero means its the first char from the response... which means the first char from the response is "<" that char... which isn't valid json... that < only happens with an error from php... or at least that's the only time it has ever come up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies... It turns out I just needed the JS, PHP, and the upload folder to all be in the same folder. Once I did that, it worked no problem. The code was good.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I am facing the same issue. I am doing this in nuxt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is returning html which is start with < tag instead of json response there. May be server error occurred.

[image]